# `enum` type always getting `0` while passing it as parameter from one viewController to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, typed

This is my `enum` :

```
typedef enum {
    ViewControllerNameSignUpViewController,
    ViewControllerNameForgotPasswordViewController,
    ViewControllerNameProfileViewController,
} ViewControllerName;
```

I want to send `ViewControllerName` from my `LeftMenuViewController` to `HomeViewController`

Code of `LeftMenuViewController` :

```
HomeViewController *controller = [HomeViewController initViewControllerWithFurtherNavigationFor:ViewControllerNameProfileViewController];
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
[navController setViewControllers:@[controller] animated:NO];
[self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
```

Code of `HomeViewController` :

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) ViewControllerName viewControllerName;
```

.

```
+ (instancetype)initViewControllerWithFurtherNavigationFor:(ViewControllerName)viewControllerName
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    HomeViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kHomeViewControllerID];

    if (controller) {
        controller.viewControllerName = viewControllerName;
    }

    return controller;
}
```

Here `controller.viewControllerName` is getting the parameter perfectly, which is `2`. But when I check it from `viewDidLoad`, it is always getting `0` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self leftMenuButtonInitialization];
    [self initialViewSetUp];
    [self furtherNavigation];
}
```

.

```
- (void)furtherNavigation
{
    if (self.viewControllerName == ViewControllerNameProfileViewController) {
        ProfileViewController *controller = [ProfileViewController initViewController];
        [controller presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Here, `self.viewControllerName` always `0`. When I set the value in my `initViewController`, Isn't it that I can access it as `self.viewControllerName` though out the class? Or I am missing something?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through 1 hour, I have found the alternative. The Problem may be relay on the calling method of `initViewControllerWithFurtherNavigationFor`.

I have called that method in `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` with `([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"goToProfileViewController"])` using segue. So I don't have to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` again. I can simply introduce it as `destinationViewController`. And then can pass any associated parameter with it. So instead of using this code :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"goToProfileViewController"]) {
    HomeViewController *controller = [HomeViewController initViewControllerWithFurtherNavigationFor:ViewControllerNameProfileViewController];
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    [navController setViewControllers:@[controller] animated:NO];
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Use this :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"goToProfileViewController"]) {
    HomeViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    controller.viewControllerName = ViewControllerNameProfileViewController;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help for this kind of problem. :)